# Why is locally synchronizable defined as $\omega\wedge \mathrm d\omega=0$?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, mathematical-physics

I'm reading GTM48: *General relativity for mathematicians*, and I have a problem about the definition of *locally synchronizable*, which is defined as $\omega\wedge \mathrm d\omega=0$.

> Let $(M,g,D)$ be a spacetime.
>
> **Definition 1** A reference frame $Q$ on a spacetime $M$ is a vector field each of whose integral curves is an observer.
>
> Let $\omega$ be the 1-form physically equivalent to $Q$, which means
> $\omega=g(Q,\cdot)$
>
> **Definition 2** $Q$ is called: locally synchronizable iff $\omega\wedge \mathrm d\omega=0$,

Why do we define *locally synchronizable* in this way?

At first, I think since Q have integral curves, Q should be integrable, so the requirement of the definition should be to do with integrability. $\omega\wedge \mathrm d\omega=0$ reminds me of *Frobenius theorem*, which tells if $\omega\wedge \mathrm d\omega=0$ then $\omega$ is integrable. That is to say, the distribution **orthogonal to $Q$** is integrable. But what we want is that $Q$ is integrable!

Do I make mistakes anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Definition 1 the vector field must be **timelike** obviously.

Yes the point is the *Frobenius theorem*. That condition, in terms of $Q$, means that locally there is a spacelike co-dimension $1$ surface $\Sigma$ everywhere orthogonal to $Q$. This is the **rest space** of the observer because the normal tangent space to $Q$ is tangent to $\Sigma$ as well. This condition, in turn, is the mathematical description of **Einstein synchronisation**: the local value of the light speed measured along lightlike curves is $1(=c)$.

As you have noticed the integrability condition of $Q$ is not referred to its integral lines that obviously do necessarily exist! It is instead referred to the existence of locally $Q$-orthogonal immersed submanifolds...